# String formatting with permutations of dictionary values

Tags: python

Here is what I currently have:

```
from collections import defaultdict

output = [{'MPID': 'A', 'CLIENTNAME': 'AAA'},
          {'MPID': 'C', 'CLIENTNAME': 'BBB'},
          {'MPID': 'C1', 'CLIENTNAME': 'CCC'},
          {'MPID': 'C2', 'CLIENTNAME': 'CCC'},
          {'MPID': 'C3', 'CLIENTNAME': 'CCC'}]

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in output:
    d[item['CLIENTNAME']].append(item['MPID'])

final = [{'CLIENTNAME': k, 'MPID': v} for k, v in d.items()]
print final
```

This output merges the `MPID` values of matching `CLIENTNAMES`.

Output:

```
[{'MPID': ['A'], 'CLIENTNAME': 'AAA'}, 
 {'MPID': ['C'], 'CLIENTNAME': 'BBB'}, 
 {'MPID': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'], 'CLIENTNAME': 'CCC'}]
```

What I am trying to do now is format a string with all permutations of each MPID, but ONLY if the dictionary contains more than 1 MPID. (in this example, only CCC has more than 1 MPID).

Here is the query I am formatting:

```
query = '''x = '{}' and y = '{}' union 
           x = '{}' and y = '{}';'''
```

This query needs to compare all MPIDS against one another. The desired output would be:

```
'''x = 'C1' and y = 'C2' union 
   x = 'C2' and y = 'C1';'''

'''x = 'C2' and y = 'C3' union 
   x = 'C3' and y = 'C2';'''

'''x = 'C1' and y = 'C3' union 
   x = 'C3' and y = 'C1';'''
```

As you can see, X and Y values swap places in the second line of the string.

What would be an efficient way of going about this part?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `combinations` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import combinations

combos = list(combinations(final[2]['MPID'], 2))
combos.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
for combo in combos:
    a, b = combo
    print '''x = '{}' and y = '{}' union 
               x = '{}' and y = '{}';'''.format(a, b, b, a)
```

This prints:

```
x = 'C1' and y = 'C2' union 
               x = 'C2' and y = 'C1';
x = 'C1' and y = 'C3' union 
               x = 'C3' and y = 'C1';
x = 'C2' and y = 'C3' union 
               x = 'C3' and y = 'C2';
```

You may need to adjust the `sort` `key` if that order matters to you.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't doing anything. If I print out `combos` after you define it, it's an empty list.

Comment: is `final[2]['MPID']` the correct target for how you have it?

Comment: That was just an example output. It can be different. The 3rd one in the output isn't always the one that has multiple values. It should be dynamic.

Comment: Right, I mean you could loop over it and do this but I just wanted to show you how you would generally go about it.

Comment: If you are having trouble getting my example to run, you can see it running at: https://repl.it/repls/VastMistyProcess. I added a loop there. Nothing will print if there are no combinations to work with.